# Do I need pipes with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular, performance, angular2-changedetection

Now I use pure pipes instead of method calls in templates for performance reasons (I just wrap method calls in pipes)

I noticed that now I use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and async pipe in all components, hence I want to remove my pipes

Do I need custom pure pipes with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I do

Custom pipe's logic is called only when arguments change, unlike method calls in templates, which, even with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, are called in every change detection cycle, even when change didn't touch method's arguments